# 2nd Iteration adding extra character in Pandas/Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I am running the code below and it is running fine for the first iteration and when the second iteration starts it gives me a key error. I notice that the there is a string "L" added to the key automatically when the second iteration starts. 
Link to my code below:

[Code for KNN having issues here](https://github.com/amandeepsharma89/datascience/blob/master/KNN.py)

Link for the data that I am using is below:

[Data used for the code](https://github.com/amandeepsharma89/datascience/tree/master/data)

Not sure why it is happening. Can someone pls let me know what is causing the issue. Help is greatly appreciated!!
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/myScripts/KNN.py", line 114, in <module>
    pred_lst.append(predict_output_of_query(10.0, features_train, df_housePrice_train, features_test[i]))
  File "C:/Python27/myScripts/KNN.py", line 96, in predict_output_of_query
    avg1 += output_train["price"][i]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 557, in __getitem__
    result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.py", line 1790, in get_value
    return self._engine.get_value(s, k)
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 103, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas\index.c:3204)
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 111, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas\index.c:2903)
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 157, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:3843)
  File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 303, in pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:6525)
  File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 309, in pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:6463)
KeyError: 6818L`

Comment: If you dump your whole code and data here, I don't think you will get many responses. Try to isolate your problem, and make it concise and to the point. Then, you will get a lot more response.

Comment: @Hun provided the code with the data so that someone can directly run the code an see the error. It has to perform the previous steps to reach this step where I am having the error

Comment: Still quite long code and a large set of data. Just look at other questions and see how other people who get multiple answers do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, I looked only at your `get_numpy_data` definition and think that it doesn't work as you'd expect. For example, the line

```
features_train, output_train = get_numpy_data(df_housePrice_train, feature_list, 'price')
```

seems to modify `df_housePrice_train`. And `output_train` becomes an np array containing a string `"price"`.

---

**Update:**

The line `distances = []` should really be inside the function `compute_distances`. This function appends elements to `distances` on every execution. Next, indices (positions) of some of the elements are applied to a data frame. On first execution everything works fine, but later the list grows and some indices get larger - exceeding the size of the data frame.

**Update 2**

For completeness: `KeyError: 6818L` means that the long integer 6818 (L denotes a type here) is not a valid key in `df_housePrice_train`.

Needed code modification:

```
## KNN.py, line 61:
#distances = []        # <- delete this line

def compute_distances(features_instances, features_query):
    distances = []     # <-- add here
    # rest of the function body...
```

Comment: yes thank you for pointing that out. However, that does not seem to be the issue (replaced it with df_housePrice_train['price'] though). Code is updated on GIT. So, what it is doing is if initially the key is 6818 in the second iteration it is for some reason looks for 6818L and throws a keyerror

Comment: Fund it. I think this answers the question. But I haven't checked the whole code, so can't guarantees its correctness.

Comment: Hi that did not answer my question

Comment: When I run it, I get the answer `[881300.0, 431860.0, 460595.0, 430200.0, 766750.0, 667420.0, 350032.0, 512800.70000000001, 484000.0, 457235.0]`. Can you update the git code and paste the full error?

Comment: Hi ptrj the code is updated on git. When I run the code following is the error
"KeyError: 6818L". So the first iteration runs fine if you uncomment 
"#print "neigh for house", i"

During the 2nd iteration a character "L" gets appended to the key values in my case above 6818..Not sure why is L appending to the key

Comment: The letter L (as in 1L) means it is a long integer (numeric type in Python 2). It's not an error. The error is KeyError - key out of range. I explained why it happens. Your code on github is not updated. You should remove `distances = []` from line 61 and put it inside the function `compute_distances`. Hope this solves the problem.

Comment: ptrj thanks for looking into it. Yes, your solution is correct! Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: Glad I could help. Feel free to [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you feel so.

Comment: Did that.. Thanks again